# Calling variable functions based on name

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I would like to be able to iterate through a loop and call two sets of functions based on ..something - something that I can iterate through, such as a string list. Here is an example of my situation:

```
def Check(name):
    return not_important

def DrawA():
    draw_a_stuff
def DrawB():
    draw_b_stuff
def DrawC():
    draw_c_stuff

list = [ "A","B","C" ]
for type in list:
    if Check(type):
        continue

    func = get_function_in_this_module( "Draw" + type )
    func() # call drawing function
```

What would be the simplest way to do something like this? It will be used to draw UI sections of a panel based on which sections are visible/available.

Comment: Just use func = eval( "Draw" + type ).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a python question specific to blender and will be more on-topic on one of programming-specific stackexchange sites.

Comment: I guess you're right. Sorry about that. Should have posted there. Thanks lemon!

Comment: Just wanted to make sure it was clear that I did not know about `eval(*)`. Extremely useful function, thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put references to the functions in a dictionary, using the names you want to invoke them by as keys, and the references as value.

```
functions={"A":DrawA, # The function name *must not* be followed by parentheses
"B":DrawB,
"C":DrawC
}
```

Then, you only have to check if `type` is in the dictionary, and call the function using `functions[type](...)`.

(Edited for clarity in regard to the lack of parentheses)

Comment: This is a great way to organize it. I haven't started using dictionaries for data, apart from Blender values, but I can see how this would be better. You specifically note the lack of parentheses - what does that accomplish here? Wouldn't that cause all entries to go into a single dimensional list? I'm also not sure what operator `:` is doing. Apparently I need to read up on using these. Thanks for showing me this.

Comment: Ah, I just looked it up. It creates key : value pairs. And after trying to set this up, I realized you meant there were no parentheses on the function names, rather than not using nested tuples. Just wanted to point that out to anyone new to this stuff.

Comment: Nice catch! I edited the code to remark on that.